# Dirty database after failed test run, how to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tdd, bdd

For my tests I'm using the combination of the latest Rspec, FactoryGirl, Guard against a local SQLite database. When I'm developing BDD-style, I will often write a failing test that has the likelihood of leaving some garbage data behind in the DB, I think especially if there's an interpreter error.

I'm often forced to delete the DB and re-migrate in order to restore it to a clean state, which is time consuming and a pain. It seems that most of the times Rspec's own rollback mechanism does a fine job, but sometimes it's not enough.

What is the proper way of handling this situation? Should the DB be wiped every single time a single test is being executed? Is database_cleaner going to do a better job than Rspec?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Three ways spring to mind.

One, wrap your tests in a transaction, and rollback at the end.

Two, use an in-memory DB that can be created/torn down very quickly

Three, Mock out your DB connection entirely and perform validation based on DB calls that are made.